# induced connection on open sets

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. If $\nabla$ is a linear connection on $M$, I would like to induce a unique linear connection on an open subset $U\subseteq M$. I know that for all $p\in U$ there is  a natural isomorphism $T_pU\cong T_pM$, so I can restrict global vector fields to local vector fields on $U$. Unfortunately there are some local vector fields on $U$ that don't came from a restriction of global vector fields.

For this reason I can't find a reasonable linear connection $\nabla^U$ over $U$ induced by $\nabla$. I need help.

Answer (score 2):

The connection $\nabla$ on a manifold $M$ is a local operator. The value of $\nabla_X(Y)$ at a point $p \in M$ depends only on $X_p$ and the value of $Y$ in an arbitrary small neighborhood around $p$. This is enough to define the connection on $TU$ when $U \subset M$ is an open subset, without extending the vector fields involved to the whole of $M$. More generally, you may want to read about the pullback of a connection which allows you to restrict a connection to more general submanifolds and even more.

Comment: The proposition about the local behavior of the connection says:
If Y and Z are GLOBAL vector fields that coincide on an open neighborhood of $p$ then $\nabla_XY=\nabla_XZ$ (The same thing is true for $X$). I don't understand in which way I can apply this statement to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take an open cover $\{U_j\}$ of $U$ given by relatively compact open sets in $U$ and a partition of unity $\{\phi_j\}$ subordinated to $\{U_j\}$ (i.e. $\mathrm{supp}\phi_j\subset U_j$).

For any vector-field $X$ on $U$, $X=\sum \phi_j\cdot X$ and $\phi_j X$ is a vector-field on $M$. Therefore we can define
$$\nabla^U_XY=\sum\nabla_{\phi_j X}Y$$
and
$$\nabla^U_YX=\sum\nabla_Y\phi_j X$$
The definition is locally meaningful, because the covering is locally finite, and so are the sums.

Hope it helps.

Comment: why $\phi_jX$ is a vector field on $M$? For every $p\in U$ we have that $(\phi_jX)_p=\phi(p)X_p$, but if $p$ is in $X\setminus U$ what is the sense?

Comment: The point is that on $X\setminus U$, we have $\phi(p) = 0$, so it doesn't matter what you choose for $X_p$ - even if you choose some horribly discontinuous thing for $X_p$, $\phi(p) X_p = 0_p$.  So $\phi X$ is still a smooth vector field on all of $M$.

Comment: So is $\sum\phi_jX$  the extension of $X$ to the whole $M$? This means that every local vector field can be extended.

Comment: @Galoisfan:  Well, I'm thinking more about $\phi X$ than $\sum \phi_j X$.  Note that $\phi X$ is *not* an extension of $X$ to all of $M$ because there are points $p\in U$ with $\phi(p)X_p \neq X_p$.  It's more like:  Shrink $X$ to an even smaller open subset and then extend the smaller thing to all of $M$.

Comment: No, $\sum\phi_j X$ is the vector-field $X$, which is a section of $TM$ on $U$; but the things you add up, $\phi_j X$ for each $j$, can be extended to global sections, just define them to be zero outside $U$. A locally finite series of global sections is by no means bound to be a global section, unless you have some kind of uniform estimates.

Comment: Actually, you can combine what I'm saying with what levap said... with the terminology of Jason DeVito, you shrink down $X$ considering it only around a point $p$ and cutting it off with a smooth function, then you extend this things to be 0 outside, obtaining a global object. The germ of this vector-field in $p$ and the germ of the original one coincide, therefore you can define the connection on germs and, by the locality property, you know it's well defined and that everything works.

Comment: Ok now it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E$ over $M$ one can show two things:

1. If two sections $X,Y$ of $TM$  agree at a point $p$ then $(\nabla_X\psi)_p=(\nabla_Y\psi)_p$ for all sections $\psi$ of $E$.
2. If two sections $\phi,\psi$   agree locally arround $p$ then $(\nabla_X\phi)_p=(\nabla_X\psi)_p$ for all sections $X$ of $TM$.

Furthermore:

3. Any $X_p\in T_pM$ can be extended to a section of $TM$.
4. For any  open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ and any $\psi\in E_{|U}$ there exists a section $\tilde{\psi}$ of $E$ which locally arround $p$ agrees with $\psi$ (just take a chart multiply by a suitable bump function and set it $0$ elsewhere).

Now you can define the induced connection $\nabla'$ as follows:

$$(\nabla'_X\psi)_p=(\nabla_\tilde{X}\tilde \psi)_p $$

where $\tilde{X}$ is any extension of $X_p$  and $\tilde \psi$ is any local extension of $\psi$. By the above this is independent of the choice of $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde \psi$.